# Multiple Linear Regression and MSE from R

Tags: r, linear-regression

have a dataset (found here- https://netfiles.umn.edu/users/nacht001/www/nachtsheim/Kutner/Appendix%20C%20Data%20Sets/APPENC01.txt) and I have done some R coding for linear regression. In the attached dataset the columns are not labeled. I had to label the columns of the dataset and save it as a csv and I apologize I can't get that on here… but the columns I am using are column 3(age) column 4(infection) column 5 (culratio) column 10 (census) and column 12(service), column 9 (region). I named the dataset hospital.

I am supposed to "For each geographic region, regress infection risk (Y) against the predictor variables age, culratio, census, service using a first order regression model. Then I need to find the MSE for each region. This is the code I have.

```
NE<- subset(hospital, region=="1")
NC<- subset(hospital, region=="2")
S<- subset(hospital, region=="3")
W<- subset(hospital, region=="4")
```

then to do a first order linear regression model I use the basic code for each

```
NE.Model<- lm(NE$infection~ NE$age + NE$culratio + NE$census + NE$service)
summary(NE.Model)
```

and I can get the adjusted R squared value, but how do I find MSE from this output?

Comment: `mean(NE.Model$residuals^2)` should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving my comment to an answer. The "errors" or "residuals" are part of the model object, `NE.Model$residuals`, so getting the mean square error is as easy as that: `mean(NE.Model$residuals^2)`.

Just as a note, you could do this in fewer steps by fitting a `region` fixed effect term in your model and then calculating the MSE for each subset of the residuals. Same difference, really.

Comment: thanks so much.. I have another question but I am unable to post it right now because I just posted this one. How would I find a 98% confidence interval for the relationship between two variables in this case? I have the code g<- lm(hospital$infection~hospital$medschool)
    predict(g, interval="confidence", level=.98) but it returns way too many results, how do I just get one interval?

Comment: @hk47 I like the `arm` package for it's `se.coef` function, which extracts the standard errors of the coefficients. So the width of your CI is `se.coef(NE.Model)` times whatever alpha level you want, e.g. `qnorm(0.975)` for 95% or `qnorm(0.99)` for 98%.